# Limsup inequality - how do I write this as a rigorous proof?

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: 1. Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be bounded sequences of real numbers. Prove that $$\limsup _{n\to \infty}(a_n+b_n)\leq \limsup _{n\to \infty}a_n + \limsup _{n\to \infty}b_n,$$ and that equality holds when $(a_n)$ or $(b_n)$ is convergent.

Weak Proof:

Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$be bounded sequences of real numbers. Then the limit superior of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are defined $$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}a_k
$$ $$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}b_k.
$$ Note that $\{(j,k): j,k \geq n, j=k\} \subset \{(j,k): j,k \geq n\}$. Then $$
\sup_{k\ge n}\,(a_k+b_k)=\sup_{\substack{j\ge n\\k\ge n\\j=k}}\,(a_j+b_k)
$$ and 
$$
\sup_{k\ge n}a_k+\sup_{k\ge n}b_k=\sup_{\substack{j\ge n\\k\ge n}}\,(a_j+b_k).
$$ Since $\sup_{\substack{j\ge n\\k\ge n\\j=k}}\,(a_j+b_k)$ is over a smaller set than $\sup_{\substack{j\ge n\\k\ge n}}\,(a_j+b_k)$, we have $$
\sup_{k\ge n}\,(a_k+b_k)\le\sup_{k\ge n}a_k+\sup_{k\ge n}b_k.
$$ Taking the limit of both sides we get $$\limsup _{n\to \infty}(a_n+b_n)\leq \limsup _{n\to \infty}a_n + \limsup _{n\to \infty}b_n.$$

Thanks for help. I also need to prove equality when either sequence is convergent.

Comment: I think your proof is pretty good.

Comment: @Pocholapantera Knowing my professor, this proof is sure to get marked down. Are you sure this is good enough?

Comment: Yes, I do (but I am not your professor). Just a comment: At the end of the proof, when you take limit of both sides, you are using that if the limits exist, then the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits. Something you are asked to prove. So, you must prove that.

Comment: If $a<b$then $\lim a< \lim b$, right? The limit exists of those sup functions because they are descreasing

Comment: Your proof is fine. The limits exist because the sequences are non-decreasing, and addition is continuous, hence you can interchange addition and limits.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_n \to a$. Then all you need to show is $\limsup_n (a_n+b_n) \ge a + \limsup_n b_n$

Choose a subsequence $b_{n_k}$ such that $b_{n_k} \to \overline{b} = \limsup_n b_n$. Clearly $a_{n_k} \to a$ since $a_n \to a$.

Then $a_{n_k}+b_{n_k} \to a+ \overline{b}$, and so $\limsup_n (a_n+b_n) \ge \lim_k (a_{n_k}+b_{n_k}) = a+ \overline{b} = \limsup_n a_n + \limsup_n b_n$.

Comment: What happens in the case that $a_n$ is not convergent?

Comment: In the first part of the proof I cannot assume either sequence is convergent.

Comment: Your proof above seems fine to me. I was just answering your last question.

Comment: Oh, okay. But in the last line you have an inequality. You showed equality for $lim_k ...$, but what about $lim_n ...$?

Comment: I don't understand. I showed that $\limsup_n (a_n + b_n) \ge \limsup_n a_n + \limsup_n b_n$. You already established the $\le$ part?